# Changing time parameters with urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, urllib

I need to change the to and from parameters, but urllib collects everything incorrectly.
In the dictionary, the parameters change correctly, but then the old url is collected.

```
import urllib.parse
url = 'http://192.168.150.138:3000/render/d-solo/htddR-gGz/jmeter-dashboard?orgId=1&from=1589972154000&to=1589972739000&var-data_source=InfluxDB-Jmeter&var-application=application%20name&var-transaction=HTTP%20Request%20-%20homepage&var-measurement_name=jmeter&var-send_interval=5&panelId=23&width=1600&height=500&tz=Europe%2FMoscow'

urlStr: urllib.parse.ParseResult = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
urlDict = urllib.parse.parse_qs(urlStr.query)
print(urlDict)
urlDict['from'] = ['1555926954000']
urlDict['to'] = ['1555938339000']
print(urlDict)
urlStr._replace(query=urllib.parse.urlencode(urlDict))
print(urlStr.geturl())

[Output]:
{'orgId': ['1'], 'from': ['1589972154000'], 'to': ['1589972739000'], 'var-data_source': ['InfluxDB-Jmeter'], 'var-application': ['application name'], 'var-transaction': ['HTTP Request - homepage'], 'var-measurement_name': ['jmeter'], 'var-send_interval': ['5'], 'panelId': ['23'], 'width': ['1600'], 'height': ['500'], 'tz': ['Europe/Moscow']}
{'orgId': ['1'], 'from': ['1555926954000'], 'to': ['1555938339000'], 'var-data_source': ['InfluxDB-Jmeter'], 'var-application': ['application name'], 'var-transaction': ['HTTP Request - homepage'], 'var-measurement_name': ['jmeter'], 'var-send_interval': ['5'], 'panelId': ['23'], 'width': ['1600'], 'height': ['500'], 'tz': ['Europe/Moscow']}
http://192.168.150.138:3000/render/d-solo/htddR-gGz/jmeter-dashboard?orgId=1&from=1589972154000&to=1589972739000&var-data_source=InfluxDB-Jmeter&var-application=application%20name&var-transaction=HTTP%20Request%20-%20homepage&var-measurement_name=jmeter&var-send_interval=5&panelId=23&width=1600&height=500&tz=Europe%2FMoscow
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think _replace does not do a in-place replace. Try assigning the returned value back to urlStr

```
urlStr=urlStr._replace(query=urllib.parse.urlencode(urlDict, doseq=True))
```

Comment: It's works, but now it creates the wrong link with "[]" in values: 
http://192.168.150.138:3000/render/d-solo/htddR-gGz/
jmeter-dashboard?orgId=['1']&
from=['1555926954000']&to=['1555938339000']

Comment: `doseq=True` in urlencode appears to fix it. Updated the answer.